# Special type of convexity

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Does anyone know if there is a name for a function $f:W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ($W$ is a vector space) that satisfies
$$
f\left(\theta x + \left(1-\theta\right) y\right) \leq \theta^\alpha f\left(x\right) + \left(1-\theta\right)^\alpha f\left(y\right)
$$
for all $\theta\in\left[0,1\right]$, $x\in W$ and $y\in W$?

Note that when $f\left(x\right)\geq0$ for all $x$ and $\alpha\geq1$ the above implies convexity.
Likewise, when $f\left(x\right)\leq0$ for all $x$ and $\alpha \leq 1$ also implies convexity.

Comment: Do you know any nonnegative nonzero $f$ such that this holds for some $\alpha\gt1$?

Comment: Sure. Any function that is both nonnegative and homogeneous of order $\alpha > 1$ will trivially satisfy that property.

Example: $f\left(x\right)=x^\alpha$ with $W$ as the set of all positive (you said nonzero) real numbers.

Edit: Woops, actually I guess that would satisfy the concave version of this.

Comment: If you are saying that $f(x)=x^2$ is such that $f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)\leqslant\theta^2f(x)+(1-\theta)^2f(y)$ for every $\theta$ in $(0,1)$, I recommend to check again. Otherwise, let me ask again: do you know any nonnegative nonzero function such that the inequality in the second line of the post holds for some $\alpha>1$?

Comment: Yeah sorry; see my edit. No I do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to invoke some kind of "hyper-convexity" property of functions. In this context, the following result might have a sobering effect:

> Assume that $\alpha\gt1$ and that $f\geqslant0$ is such that $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leqslant t^\alpha f(x)+(1-t)^\alpha f(y)$ for every $x\ne y$ and every $t$ in $(0,1)$. Then $f=0$.

To show this, for every $u\gt0$, consider the property:

> $P(u)$ : $f\geqslant0$ and $f(\frac12(x+y))\leqslant u(f(x)+f(y))$ for every $x\ne y$.

Assume that $P(u)$ holds for some $u\lt\frac12$. Let $x\ne y$. Consider $z=\frac12(x+y)$, $r=\frac12(x+z)$ and $s=\frac12(z+y)$. Then $f(r)\leqslant u(f(x)+f(z))$, $f(s)\leqslant u(f(z)+f(y))$, and $z=\frac12(r+s)$ hence $f(z)\leqslant u(f(s)+f(t))$. Thus, $f(z)\leqslant u^2(f(x)+2f(z)+f(y))$, and $f(z)\leqslant k(u)(f(x)+f(y))$ with $k(u)=u^2/(1-2u^2)$. That is, $P(k(u))$ holds.

This shows the implication $P(u)\implies P(k(u))$. Iterating this, one sees that, for every $n$, $f$ satisfies $P(u_n)$ where $u_0=u$ and $u_n=k(u_{n-1})$. Since $u_n\to0$ as soon as $u\lt\frac12$ and $f\geqslant0$, this shows that $f(\frac12(x+y))=0$ for every $x\ne y$, that is, $f=0$.

Finally, if $f\geqslant0$ satisfies $P(u)$ with $u=\left(\frac12\right)^\alpha$ and $\alpha\gt1$, then $u\lt\frac12$ hence $f=0$.